# Swift: A function as an another functions argument

Tags: swift, swift2

**EDIT: I'm aware that I was using the wrong Xcode version for Swift 2, now. Problem solved.**

I'm following the Swift 2 book from Apple. At a point there's the following example:

```
    import Foundation

func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

What I think is weird is the last line. Why does it say `condition: lessThanTen` and not just `lessThanTen`? My compiler (Xcode) also gives me an error doing it the way it's shown in the book.

Also: why does it only say `list: [Int]` in the third line but `condition: Int -> Bool`? Why not something like `list: [Int] -> Int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It says `condition: lessThanTen` because in Swift you can define "labels", that is, descriptions for the data that a function call requires. It gives you an error because the call would be correct if the function declaration was `func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], #condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool` (at least this would be the case with Swift 1.2). The number sign produces, inside every call to the function, a label identical to the name of the function argument. Said label must not be deleted from the call, since it's there to clarify the purpose of that parameter to whoever invokes the function.
2. `list: [Int]` means that the first function argument takes name "list" and is of type [Int]. `condition: Int -> Bool` means that the second function argument takes name "condition" and is of type "Int to Bool", that is, `condition` is a function that takes a single argument of type `Int` and returns a value of type `Bool`. In fact, if you read the last line, in the call to the function `hasAnyMatches` the following are passed: i) an array of `Ints` and ii) a function that takes an `Int` and returns a `Bool` (note that when passing functions as parameters we only write their name - no parentheses).

Comment: 1. Changing the line to  `func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], #condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool` removes that error! 'Using' that label is not required but makes the program easier to read, right?

Comment: Exactly. Labels are not compulsory but they will make the code more readable and explicit.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! 2. What difference would it make if I write `list: [Int] -> Int` at the function declaration? Would it make a difference at all? Would it still run?

Comment: It wouldn't run anymore because `list: [Int] -> Int` describes a function parameter of type "array of Ints to int", which stands for a function that takes an array of `Ints` as its only argument and returns a value of type `Int`. You would be instead passing it an array of `Ints`, not a function.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway be aware that my explanation is correct for Swift 1.2 (you're most likely using Xcode 6). Swift 2.0 works slightly differently so see @matt 's answer too.

Comment: I'm aware of that now! I didn't know that swift 2 only works with Xcode 7 beta.

Answer (score 2):

Swift functions and methods can define their parameters to either have external names or not.

> By default, the first parameter omits its external name, and the
>   second and subsequent parameters use their local name as their
>   external name.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

The the tag `condition:` is the external name for the closure that you are passing to your hasAnyMatches function.

That code should compile and run.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't compile or run. Xcode says the following: _Issue: Extraneous argument label 'condition:' in call.
Fix-it: Delete "condition:"_ It works fine if I delete _condition:_.

Comment: @MustangXY gave the hint that there might be a typo (a missing # in the functions declaration). Now it runs without any problems!

Comment: It's not a typo. It's because you're using the wrong version of Swift for testing. See my answer...

Answer (score 2):

> My compiler (Xcode) also gives me an error doing it the way it's shown in the book.

Because the language has changed! In Swift 2, which you are *reading* about, the function has `condition:` so your call must have `condition:`. But you are *testing* in Swift 1.2, a very different language, where the rules are not the same.

In Swift 1.2, a top-level function declared with `condition:` means that your call should *not* have `condition:`. In Swift 1.2, to require the call to have `condition:`, the function declaration would have to say `# condition:`.

You are confusing yourself. Update Xcode so that the language you are using is the same as the language you are reading about.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I didn't know that Swift 2 only works with Xcode 7 Beta.